# Why aren't identical arrays, when passed as strings considered equal?

Tags: java, arrays

1)  if I set

```
int[] set1 = new int[]{1, 2};
int[] set2 = new int[]{1, 2};
```

how come when I pass them as strings using

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set1) == Arrays.toString(set2));
```

it returns false?

2)  Is there any way to compare equality of entire arrays without looping through each index of the array?

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`.

Comment: Also why don't you use `Arrays.equals(set1, set2)` ?

Comment: So, you found Arrays.toString() in the javadoc, but didn't find [Arrays.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int[],%20int[]%29)

Comment: A good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/767379/1399567

Comment: Use `Arrays.equals()` for comparing 1-dimensional arrays or `Arrays.deepEquals()` for multidimensional ones.

Comment: @James Montagne oh yeah.  brain fart. lol.. thanks. Been working on too many integer problems

Comment: @JB Nizet nope. I didn't find it in the javadoc.  I found it by googling.  But thanks.  now I have a point of reference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `String`s are `Object`s, so they should be compared using `equals`:

   ```
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set1).equals(Arrays.toString(set2))); //prints true
   ```
2. Use [`Arrays#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5b%5d,%20int%5b%5d%29) to compare arrays, note that the arrays must have the same length and the items must be equals: `==` for primitives (`int`, `long` ...) and `equals` for `Object` references).

Answer (score 4):

1. `==` compares string *references*, not values. Use `str1.equals(str2)`. (more information on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/); it basically compare whether the actual objects are the same, not the string content)
2. No, naturally if you want to know if each element is the same you'll have to loop through all of them. `Arrays#toString` does this behind the scenes also (how else would it get a string representation?).

Sidenote: converting an array to a string introduces a lot of unnecessary overhead (string manipulation, etc.). You should probably just loop through and compare elements, or create a helper method (or use a built-in one like `Arrays#equals`).

Comment: thanks.  the string conversion was a work-around to see if two arrays were equal without having to loop through each index.  This of course was before you guys indicated that I could use Arrays.equals().  What does Arrays#equals do as opposed to Arrays.equals?

Comment: @Stuart `#` is simply the commonly used notation for referencing a method. They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Arrays.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) to compare arrays and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for Strings comparisons.